# I have some diffculty count a(n) = the number of Niven (Harshad) numbers exceeding N

Tags: math

> Harshad/Niven numbers are positive numbers that are divisible by the sum of their digits. All single-digit numbers are Harshad numbers.
> For example, 27 is a Harshad number as 2 + 7 = 9, and 9 is a divisor of 27.
> Count a(n) = the number of Niven (Harshad) numbers exceeding n (n<=1e12)

We can define the function checkHarshad(n) (Calculate sum of digits of n and check whether n%S(n)), then count the number of Harshad numbers in range [1..n]. But the program just run fast if n <= 1e7

> > Hiroaki Yamanouchi had a python code that calculate a(10^n), but I don't understand it, and I don't think it's helpful to my problem if n <= 1e12.

```
def number_of_niven_numbers(digits):
  """
  - Count the number of Niven numbers 
    less than or equal to 10^digits.
  """
  N = digits
  ret = 0

  cnts = [0] * (digits + 1)

  for digit_sum in range(1, N * 9 + 1):
    curr = [[0] * digit_sum]
    curr[0][0] = 1

    next_mods = [0] * digit_sum
    for i in range(digit_sum):
      next_mods[i] = 10 * i % digit_sum

    for left_digits in range(N):
      left_sum_max = min(9 * left_digits, digit_sum)
      next = [[0] * digit_sum for _ in range(min(left_sum_max + 9, digit_sum) + 1)]

      for left_sum in range(left_sum_max + 1):
        for left_mod in range(digit_sum):
          cnt = curr[left_sum][left_mod]
          if cnt == 0:
            continue
          next_mod_base = next_mods[left_mod]
          for next_digit in range(min(min(digit_sum, 9), digit_sum - left_sum) + 1):
            next_sum = left_sum + next_digit
            next_mod = next_mod_base + next_digit
            if next_mod >= digit_sum:
              next_mod -= digit_sum
            next[next_sum][next_mod] += cnt

      curr = next
      if digit_sum < len(curr):
        cnts[left_digits + 1] += curr[digit_sum][0]

  return cnts[N] + 1
```

**So, how can we calculate a(n) up to 1e12?**

Comment: Are you asking a question about code? If so -- show the code. If not -- Stack Overflow isn't an appropriate place to ask math questions. In either case, your question isn't very clear. Please clarify your actual question, and have it not depend upon external links.

Comment: So whats your question?

Comment: @derpirscher, As I have concerned in my topic, count a(n) = the number of Niven (Harshad) numbers exceeding n (n<=1e12)

Comment: @HiểnNguyễnMinh: Yes, you said that already. What is your question? This is a Q&A site. If you seek the A, you need to at least provide a Q.

Comment: My question is how to calculate a(n) up to 1e12

Comment: Well, you proposed a method for doing that (ie iterate from 1 to n and check if `n % sum(n) == 0`).

Comment: Yup, and I think I can calculate a(10^n)

Comment: So again: What's your question? If this works for the first 1000000 numbers, why wouldn't it work for the next 10000000000 numbers too? It will probably take some time but it will without any doubt work. If you are searching for a more efficient solution exploiting some clever mathematical properties, you should probably ask at https://math.stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved by using `digit dp` by fixing a sum of digits and calculating numbers less than n that is divisible by this sum.

Sample Cpp code.

```
#define ll long long
string s;
ll dp[20][200][200][2];
ll recur(ll ind,ll sum,ll div,ll fix,ll flag){
     if(ind==s.size(){
          if(div==0 and sum==0) return 1;
          return 0;
     }
     if(dp[ind][sum][div][flag]!=-1) return dp[ind][sum][div][flag];
     ll ans=0;
     ll l=0,r=9;
     if(flag) r=s[ind]-'0';
     for(int i=l;i<=r;i++){
          if(sum>=i) ans+=recur(ind+1,sum-i,(div*10+i)%fix,fix,flag&(i==r));
     }
     return dp[ind][sum][div][flag]=ans;
}


void dk(){
     ll n;
     cin>>n;
     s=to_string(n);
     ll ans=0;
     for(int i=1;i<=11*9;i++){ // possible sum from 1 to 12*9+1 since n<=1e12
          memset(dp,-1,sizeof(dp));
          ans+=recur(0,i,0,i,1);
     }
     cout<<ans<<endl;
}
```

Here the for loop in `dk()` function is fixing a sum and the digit dp is finding number less than or equal to n such that the numbers are divisible by sum `i`

In the digit dp the `div` is keeping track of current number mod by sum, since the number should be divisible by sum, hence finally `div` should be equal to 0 for that number to be valid.

Time Complexity= `O(110*10*log_10^3(n)*2)`

You can study about digit dp in here

[Usaco Link](https://usaco.guide/gold/digit-dp?lang=cpp)

[Codeforces Link](https://codeforces.com/blog/entry/53960)